# How to add more than 1 shape in single xml drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xml-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I want to create chat bubble using xml resource but i'm not able to make triangle outside of rectangle with right edge i also tried with 9 patch image but when user enters 1 character still it width is not as wrap content. please help me i also put created code of xml resouce.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#5EB888"/>
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>


<item
    android:bottom="-1000dp"
    android:right="200dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:top="190dp">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/android-chat-bubble-layout-9-patch-image-using-listview/

Comment: @AndroidSurya i had created 9 patch image but it not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out these libraries**

It may help you (Y)

[Bubble 1](https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2609)

[Bubble 2](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3564)

[Bubble 3](https://github.com/dupengtao/BubbleTextView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2238)

Comment: thnxs for your answer i' check it and reply you soon

Comment: Jaymin i tried your answer but it not working properly means when i set arrow bottom with one line it looks good but when lines are more then 1 arrow not set at bottom of bubble.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working drawable `custom_shape_chat_box.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Transparent Rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Colored Rectangle -->
    <item
        android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom-Right Triangle -->
    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="-10dp"
        android:bottom="20dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="26">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_chat_box">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: i appreciate your answer but it is not OK because if i put only "hi" text in MSG still it makes big so not feasible. by the way thanks fro your answer.